# Memoir - force table captions above and figure captions below

Tags: captions, vertical-alignment, memoir

In the style that I am creating I need to force table captions to go above the table, and figure captions to go below the figure. My style is based on memoir class. I have found solutions that force caption position using the caption or floatrow package, but I am wondering if there is a solution based directly on memoir options (using the caption package overrides all memoir caption settings). What is the recommended solution for caption positioning in memoir?

Comment: Only sub-captions have placement specific counterparts. Note that the placement of the caption typically corresponds to its placement in the code. Do you normally put the `\caption` at the bottom of the float environment? If so, do you put the `\label` *inside* the `\caption` or outside/after? These consistencies might help update [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir)'s placement for specific floats...

Comment: Memoir places captions corresponding to their placement in the code, so I can get what I want if I write the code following the given placement rules. However, I am writing a PhD theses style for my university that PhD students will use and I need to guarantee that captions will be printed correctly (following the university style guidelines) even if they write incorrect code. Therefore, I must have some mechanism to force caption position regardless of how the code is written and I am wondering if I need to switch to package "caption" for that.

Comment: The `caption` package can't do this either. You need to go for `float` or `floatrow` or use `hvfloat` instead.

Comment: Can't you define new commands/environments?